# Use ref of other component into current component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My first react class is:

```
import React from 'react';
class School extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigator" ref={(input) => { this.schoolref = input; }}>
        <div className="pan ui-draggable" style={this.props.subNavDimension} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default School;
```

My second React class is:

```
import React from 'react';
class College extends React.Component {
  showshool = () => {
    //Here I want to access the ref defined in School class.
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui-college-hello">
        <section className="1" onClick={this.showschool}></section>
        <section className="2" onClick={this.showstudent}></section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default College;
```

Parent class of above both class is:

```
import React from 'react';
import School from 'School';
import College from 'College';
class ParentClass extends React.Component {
  showshool = () => {
    //Here I want to access the ref defined in School class.
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <School />
      <College />
    );
  }
}
export default ParentClass;
```

I am basically trying to access the ref of div of another component. I can't use the redux store. Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 1):

Parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import School from 'School';
import College from 'College';
class ParentClass extends React.Component {
  setRef = myComponent => this.myComponent = myComponent
  showshool = () => {
    // use this.myComponent
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <School setRef={this.setRef} />
      <College ref={this.myComponent }/>
    );
  }
}
export default ParentClass;
```

College

```
import React from 'react';
class College extends React.Component {
  showshool = () => {
    // this.props.ref
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui-college-hello">
        <section className="1" onClick={this.showschool}></section>
        <section className="2" onClick={this.showstudent}></section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default College;
```

School:

```
import React from 'react';
class School extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setRef(this.schoolref);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigator" ref={(input) => { this.schoolref = input; }}>
        <div className="pan ui-draggable" style={this.props.subNavDimension} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default School;
```

Comment: The above solution is not working.Getiing error:Original message: _this.props.setRef is not a function

Comment: I think the idea is here, but indead the setRef method expected in ParentClass doesn't exist, And with some comments or a better naming it would be more easy to undestand .

Comment: Sorry, that's correct @pdem - specify a method: `setRef = myComponent => this.myComponent = myComponent` - I've modified the answer